# Packages excluded by strict priority or samtools not found

Tags: python, conda, environment, snakemake

I have a yml file which needs to specify the package version so that it is consistent among multiple users. The yml file is activated in a Snakemake pipeline. The environment either runs into a excluded by strict repo priority error, or samtools has not been found.

Here's what I tried so far:

Version 1:

```
name: pipeline_env
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - bioconda::bcftools=1.8
  - bioconda::bedtools=2.27.1
  - bioconda::biopython=1.71
  - bioconda::bwa=0.7.15
  - bioconda::fastqc=0.11.9
  - bioconda::freebayes=1.0.2
  - bioconda::gatk=3.7
  - bioconda::htslib=1.6
  - bioconda::lofreq=2.1.3.1
  - conda-forge::numpy=1.16.6
  - conda-forge::perl=5.34.0
  - bioconda::picard=2.23.3
  - conda-forge::pip=19.3.1
  - python=3.6.10
  - bioconda::samtools=1.7
  - bioconda::vcftools=0.1.16
  - conda-forge::zlib=1.2.11
```

Error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Creating conda environment workflow/envs/main.yml...
Downloading and installing remote packages.
CreateCondaEnvironmentException:
Could not create conda environment from /net/smith/vol1/home/user/yevo_pipeline/workflow/envs/main.yml:
Command:
mamba env create --quiet --file "/net/smith/vol1/home/user/.snakemake/conda/dca10f2a3bdb2327c0d6ee1cefb17e1c_.yaml" --prefix "/net/smith/vol1/home/user/.snakemake/conda/dca10f2a3bdb2327c0d6ee1cefb17e1c_"
Output:
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
error    libmamba Selected channel specific (or force-reinstall) job, but package is not available from channel. Solve job will fail.
error    libmamba Selected channel specific (or force-reinstall) job, but package is not available from channel. Solve job will fail.
Encountered problems while solving:
  - package htslib-1.6-0 is excluded by strict repo priority
  - package pip-19.3.1-py38_0 is excluded by strict repo priority
  - package zlib-1.2.11-h516909a_1010 is excluded by strict repo priority
  - package numpy-1.16.6-py38h18fd61f_0 is excluded by strict repo priority
```

Version 2:

```
name: pipeline_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - bioconda::bcftools=1.8
  - bioconda::bedtools=2.27.1
  - bioconda::biopython=1.71
  - bioconda::bwa=0.7.15
  - bioconda::fastqc=0.11.9
  - bioconda::freebayes=1.0.2
  - bioconda::gatk=3.7
  - htslib=1.6
  - bioconda::lofreq=2.1.3.1
  - numpy=1.16.6
  - conda-forge::perl=5.34.0
  - bioconda::picard=2.23.3
  - pip=19.3.1
  - python=3.6.10
  - bioconda::samtools=1.7
  - bioconda::vcftools=0.1.16
  - zlib=1.2.11
```

Error:

Pipeline fails with:

```
samtools: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Use `flexible` priority. IMO, the insistence on `strict` priority is a bit dogmatic and is a poor heuristic for actual reproducibility. If we want real reproducibility, then we should be using legit lockfiles (e.g., `conda-lock`).

Comment: @merv How does one implement flexible priority?

Comment: You can set the user configuration with `conda config --set channel_priority flexible` (just needs to be done once at CLI, not in Snakemake)

Comment: @merv I set the channel priority to flexible, but still run into ```samtools: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory```.  From previous discussions, the channel order seems to be correct, so I'm not really sure what else can be causing the issue.

Comment: Could you ask that as a separate question? That is, we have resolved the environment creation issue and now you have a runtime error, correct?